# Can a multivariable function be defined at a certain point where the limit does not exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I watched Professor Leonard's lecture on limits and continuity of multivariable functions, where he said that a two-variable function is continuous everywhere it is defined, that is, the entire domain (if I understood correctly). And I was wondering: is it possible to have something like a jump discontinuity in a graph of three or more dimensions such that the function is defined at a certain point, but the limit doesn't exist there?

Comment: "a two-variable function is continuous everywhere it is defined" ????

Comment: That was supposed to mean that the function is continuous on its entire domain of definition.

Comment: This is not true even for functions of one variable. You misunderstood something and in consequence it is not quite clear what you are asking. Or there are some assumptions missing.

Comment: Let $f(x,y):= \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and $f(0,0):=0.$ Then $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0).$  To see this look at $f(x,x)$ for $x \ne 0.$

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I know it isn't true for one variable, but I thought it might be true for multivariable functions. In the video which I mentioned, it was written on the table that "A function is continuous at any point on the region for which it is defined (domain)."

But you confirmed my suspicion of that statement being incorrect. Thank you!

Comment: @Fred Yes, it seems fair. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you mean [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFF4mvyhAyA) at 1:44:45? On the board, that sentence is preceded by “**CONTINUITY:**” (underlined), so what he is doing is defining what it means when we say that a function is continuous. Of course it's not true for *all* functions!